# OpenLayers - Test Control To See If It Is Active

Tags: openlayers-2

I am trying to get the active state of an OpenLayers `SelectFeature` control. I create this control and add it to my map but I do NOT activate it yet. This part works fine. Here is the script to create the control and add it to the map:

```
var highlightControl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(lyrstands, {
        hover: true,        
        highlightOnly: true,                
selectStyle: {
   fill: "#0000FF",
           strokeColor: "#0000FF",
           strokeWidth: 2,
   fillOpacity: 0.5
          }
    });


map.addControl(highlightControl);
```

Then I have a button that calls a function. Here is the code for the button:

```
new OpenLayers.Control.Button({title: "Select Polygon", trigger: HiLite})
```

I know the button is calling the `HiLite` function because if I put a simple alert statement in the `HiLite` function (for example: `alert("The Function Works");`) it works correctly.

So what I am trying to do is check to see if `highlightControl` has been activated by testing the `highlightControl.active` value, if it is already activated the function should do nothing, but, if `highlightControl` is NOT activated it should activate it. Unfortunately, the function does not work. Here is the function I have written:

```
function HiLite(){
  if (highlightControl.active==false)       
          {highlightControl.activate();}
  else {}
   }
```

If I write the function to simply activate the tool without the If Else stuff it works fine. But, for some reason when written as above I cannot get the status of the Active attribute. The OpenLayers documentations states that the Active attribute is a Boolean value and I assumed I could check the status using the `highlightControl.active==false` statement.

Why can I not get this function to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe there is a problem with the visibility of your *highlightControl* variable. You could try to add an ID to your control, and than access it like this:

```
var highlightControl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(lyrstands, {
    //add ID
    id: 'Mycontrol',
    hover: true,        
    highlightOnly: true,                
selectStyle: {
fill: "#0000FF",
       strokeColor: "#0000FF",
       strokeWidth: 2,
fillOpacity: 0.5
      }
});
//then do something like this
var control = map.getControlsBy("id", "Mycontrol")[0];
    if (!control.active) {
         control.activate();
     }
```

#### EDIT

This problem was solved thanks to SirijuS. Here is the code fix:

```
var highlightControl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(lyrstands, {        
    id: 'ctrlHiLite',                
    hover: true,        
            highlightOnly: true,                     
    selectStyle: {
       fill: "#0000FF",
               strokeColor: "#0000FF",
               strokeWidth: 2,
       fillOpacity: 0.5
              }
        });

function HiLite() {

var control = map.getControlsBy("id", "ctrlHiLite")[0];
    if (!control.active) {
     control.activate();
 }
}
```

Comment: SirijuS, thank you for your response! You have solved the problem. Here is the code I used:

Comment: var highlightControl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(lyrstands, {  
  id: 'ctrlHiLite',                
  hover: true,  
                highlightOnly: true,                
  selectStyle: {
     fill: "#0000FF",
                   strokeColor: "#0000FF",
                   strokeWidth: 2,
     fillOpacity: 0.5
                  }
            });

function HiLite() {

var control = map.getControlsBy("id", "ctrlHiLite")[0];
    if (!control.active) {
         control.activate();
     }
}

Comment: I'm glad i could help.

Answer (score 1):

`highlightControl.active` starts out being `null` so checking for `false` will not work.

Use this instead:

```
if (!highlightControl.active) {
    highlightControl.activate();

}
```

Comment: CaptDragon - Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, I was not able to get your script to work. I appreciate you taking the time to respond to my problem and hope you have a great day!